# How can change action in Function of Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want change action in function AjaxUpload.
this code value of setnamefile in action not change, because page not reload.

and I think if change action when of submit, but I cannot done.

How can change action in Function of Ajax ?

html

```
<input id="namefileupload" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y").'-'.rand(0,9999); ?>" >
```

javascript

```
var setnamefile = $('#namefileupload').val();
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
    action: 'upload-file.php?savename=' + setnamefile,
    name: 'uploadfile',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){
         if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|doc|docx|pdf|xls|xlsx|pptx|ppt)$/.test(ext))){ 
            status.text('file it not support');
            return false;
        }
        status.text('Uploading...');
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response){
        status.text('');
        if(response==="success"){
            var mydate=new Date();
            var today = mydate.getDate()+ mydate.getFullYear();
            var numrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1;
            var restype = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
            $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<a href="./uploads/'+ setnamefile +'.'+restype+'" target="_blank">'+file+'</a>').addClass('success');
            $('#namefileupload').val(today+'-'+numrand);
            setnamefile = today+'-'+numrand;
        } else{
            $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: simple add `this.action='new URL'` in `onSubmit:` just before `status.text('Uploading...');`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. but it cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are having some form or related id then you can do this:

```
$("#formId").attr("action", your url);
```

use like this:

```
<button id="addImage">test</button>
new AjaxUpload($('#addImage'), {
                action: 'url,
                name: 'uploadimage',
                dataType: 'json',
                onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
                },
                onComplete: function (file, response) {
                }
            });
$('input[type="file"]').on('click', function(e){
    alert('hi!');
});
```

Comment: But function not have ID

Comment: i thought you have some form which you are trying to submit in that case use the form id.